can someone explain how serializeuser deserializeuser work here with google login and normal login
why when someone not logged in with google tries to post something the req.user gives the google id only but when its a user thats not logged in with google the req.body gives the id and the username ? is there another way to do it cause now i have to find by either the username or the google id where when the req.user gives the normal id not the google id i can directly use findbyId ?
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import ejs from "ejs"; 
import {fileURLToPath}  from "url";
import {dirname} from "path";
import mongoose from "mongoose"; 
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import passportLocalMongoose from "passport-local-mongoose";
import {Strategy as GoogleStrategy} from "passport-google-oauth20";
import findOrCreate from "mongoose-findorcreate";
const app=express();
const __filename=fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname=dirname(__filename);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(session({
    secret:"hmairaftw",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB");
const usersSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    password:String,
    googleId:String,
    secret:String
});
usersSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const User=mongoose.model("User", usersSchema)
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      return cb(null, {
        id: user._id,
        username: user.username,
        picture: user.picture,
        
      });
    });
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  });
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
      scope:["profile", "email"]
      
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            
            User.findOne({googleId:profile["id"]}).then(user=>{
                if (!user){
                    const newUser=new User({
                        
                        email:profile.emails[0].value,
                        googleId:profile.id
                    })
                    newUser.save().then(resolve=>{return done(null, newUser);}).catch(error=>{console.log(error)})
                    
                }
                else{
                    return done(null, profile)
                }

            }).catch(error=>{return done(error)})
      
    }
  ));
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("home");
});
app.get("/auth/google", 
    passport.authenticate("google", {scope:["profile", "email"]}));
app.get("/auth/google/secrets", 
    passport.authenticate("google", {failureRedirect:"/login"}),
    (req, res)=>{res.redirect("/secrets")}
);
app.get("/login", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("login");
});
app.get("/register", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("register");
});
app.get("/secrets", (req, res)=>{
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){res.render("secrets")}
    else{res.redirect("/login")}
})
app.get("/logout", (req, res)=>{
    req.logout((err)=>{
        if (err){console.log(err)}
        else{res.redirect("/")}
    })
})
app.post("/register", (req, res)=>{
    
    User.register({username:req.body.username}, req.body.password, (err, user)=>{
        if (err){console.log(err);res.redirect("/register");}
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            })
        }
    });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res)=>{
    const newUser=new User({
        username:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password
    })
    req.login(newUser, (err)=>{
        if (err){console.log(err)}
        else{
            User.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{res.redirect("/secrets")})
        }
    })
})
app.get("/submit", (req, res)=>{
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){res.render("submit")}
    else{res.redirect("/login")}
});
app.post("/submit", (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.user);
    User.findOne({$or:[{googleId:req.user.id}, {username:req.user.username}]}).then(user=>{
        user.secret=req.body.secret;
        user.save().then(resolve=>{res.redirect("/secrets")}).catch(error=>{console.log(error)})
        
    }).catch(error=>{console.log(error)});
})
app.listen(3000, ()=>{console.log("Server running on port 3000")});


in the data base both objects have an id so why i cant have them in req.user and the req.user gives this for normal logged in user in the console.log in the psot secrets route { id: '664114226ea7dd4d562090f8', username: 'bcrypt@bcrypt.bcrypt' } and this when its a google accc { id: '114126545855377460932' }
